# When the game is fair

Tags: probability, dice

One player throws dice twice.
If he has 2 x 6 on the dice he is receving 8*a.
If he has one 6 he will collect 4*a.
Otherwise (when he has no 6 at all) he is paying a.

For which value of a game is fair?

I was trying to bit that issue by using expected value (should be 0?)
But only resonable outcome seems to be 0...

Answer (score 0):

As written, the value is proportional to $a$, so $a=0$ is a solution.  I don't find another.  The value is $\frac {8a}{36}+4a\cdot \frac {10}{36} -a\cdot \frac{25}{36}=\frac {23}{36}a$

Answer (score 0):

The game is fair if $8a\times\frac{1}{36}+4a\times\frac{10}{36}=a\times\frac{25}{36}$
which is only the case if $a=0$.

Here $\frac{1}{36}$ is the probability of throwing twice a six, $\frac{10}{36}$
is the probability of throwing exactly one six and $\frac{25}{36}$
is the probability of throwing no six.